# Attach PDF to mail and open with default mail client in user computer using C#

Tags: asp.net, sendmail, email-attachments

My requirement is attach PDF file to email and open with default mail client(like outlook or windows live mail) using C# code.

This should be done with default e-mail client that the user has configured as their default.

I checked MAPI to this. However still i couldn't found proper code to do this

This is the code i used

```
 MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
        disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
        disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
        disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
        message.Attachments.Add(data);
```

Comment: This question has been answered here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328598/open-default-mail-client-along-with-a-attachment/25586282#25586282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
List<System.Net.Mail.Attachment> lstAttachment = new List<System.Net.Mail.Attachment>(); 
if (File.Exists(AttachmentFilePath))//AttachmentFilePath is path of attachment   
{
   PDF = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(AttachmentFilePath);
   PDF.Name = "DEMO_PDF.pdf";
   lstAttachment.Add(PDF);
   objMailer.Attachments = lstAttachment;//objMailer is mail client object.
}
```

Comment: That will not open the default email client