# wpf, send mail, let the user select the from field

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, email-attachments

I'm trying to launch the email app from the user click some hyper link, I want to add also attachment, the only thing that worked was this link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328598/open-default-mail-client-along-with-a-attachment), but now I don't want to specify the MailMessage.From field, I want it to be like when you click on mailto: link, it opens your deafault account or ask you to login, etc.., but whenever I try to set the mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("");,  it throws exception, it should be an email

to get my app launch the mail with attachment, now how can I remove the field "From" and let the user use his mail or something like when you use mailto:
if I remove this line, it throws exception

```
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress();
```

Comment: We need more info to help... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what about it now

Answer (score 0):

If you want your WPF application to send an e-mail directly you should use the SmtpClient Class [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

If you are trying to launch the default mail app (like outlook) to send the e-mail, I'd use Process.Start as one of the answers to the question linked specified.

```
var url = "mailto:user@domain.com";
// var url = "mailto:?subject=aSubject&body=aBody";
// var url = "mailto:?subject=aSubject&body=aBody&attachment=aFile";
Process.Start(url);
```

Comment: I'm trying to launch, but if I try to use this one  
// var url = "mailto:?subject=aSubject&body=aBody&attachment=aFile";
the file is never attached

Comment: attachment is only supported by a few e-mail clients.  I suggest you use the SmtpClient Class, it has full support for attachments.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx