# How to get the users SMTP Server credentials to send an email from the users email in C#

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

I have been trying to figure out how to send an email from the users email for this C# application that is being sent to my company's venders. it creates a unique xml file for the users to send our company. the  users email is the determining factor if the xml file gets in our system and tells us where it goes.

I tried to use the mailto but that won't allow attachments to be passed through.

I am at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: You cannot send an email from someone else's email address. That's a security restriction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open default mail client along with a attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328598/open-default-mail-client-along-with-a-attachment)